# The message is hidden in plain site

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, steganography

You’re an agent for the very secret PSE – Protection against Stupidity Establishment. The agency tries to prevent people doing stupid things, before they do them. You’ve been given a random email account and been told to wait for your next instructions, which you know will be hidden.

Finally, the email arrives, from an anonymous sender:

---

> Anyone who watches this show, wil ge*t* a heap more smart r*e*ally fast, grow your mind, teach yourself *n*ew facts! For it pr*e*vously was thought ony humans quie you*n*g bra*i*ns could grow, but now we know teens and *g*rown ps do as well! Ti*m*e we use it now for good, and use it before we t*a*ke it, this knowledge away. Even you can do it, simly *s*end us a letter and i*t* allows us access, so we can swiftly add yor name. Relax and enjoy it, all for you at last, life an be unlocked and it can be enjoyed! The show is not al, get *r*eal knowledg*e* you can get gr*e*at exper*t* real views on it, so sign up now for amaing episodes!
>
> LU – Leading Uniqueness, L for <sub>lower</sub> and U for <sup>UPPER</sup>. Call as soon as possible!

---

From experience you know that there is always the following hidden in these emails:

- a **date** for the mission
- a **time** it should be carried out
- a **code name** for you
- a **location** nearby
- an **operation name** for the mission
- **mission instructions**
- an **explanation** of why this mission is necessary

---

## Can you extract all the mission details in time?

---

Hint for the image:

> n UP1 would equal m. M DOWN1 would equal N.

Comment: Should be more of a fun one, the steganography tag is probably a bit of a giveaway already, but I’m sure you guys have already seen why it’s there :P

Comment: My most recent edit may be a small hint for the second part of rands answer. Location, instructions and explanation found so far

Answer (score 5):

Another partial.

The mission instructions are

> **Charges phone in bath: Steal all chargers!**

We get this from the clue

> "After T" (first letter of each sentence), which tells us to take the first letter after every "t".

Comment: Correct! That’s location and instructions down :)

Comment: (Also the explanation as well)

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I've managed to find, starting from the most obvious and getting progressively less so.

**Location**

> The italicised letters in the message spell out TEN ENIGMA STREET. This must be the **location**.

**Date / time / codename / operation name**

> The missing letters (L from will, I from previously, L from only, T from quite, U from ups, P from simply, U from your, C from can, L from all, Z from amazing) spell LILTUPUCLZ. Using the note about *lower* and *UPPER*, this becomes `itPCz`, which leads us to [an Imgur image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itPCz.png) as follows:
>
>  [image]

Now, from this,

> modify `uNdER` by the indicated amounts backwards and forward in the alphabet to get `eSqRX` and [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSqRX.png), which gives the **date** as 25/04/20 and the **time** as 12:00.
>
>  And modify `oNTOp` by the indicated amounts backwards and forward in the alphabet to get `gMUIk` and [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMUIk.png), which I suppose indicates where to find all the information. I'd already figured out the date and time, but this seems to mean your **code name** is Beastly Gerbil and the **operation name** is "hidden in plain site".

**<s>Time</s> instructions / explanation**

> The first letters in all sentences spell out AFTERT. I guessed "after tea" is the **time** of the mission, but [@Jens found the correct solution here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/97312/5373).

**Other ideas not used**

4. > The last letters in all sentences spell out SLYEDS. Not sure if that's significant. Could it be the **operation name**?
5. > The number of words in each sentence is 20, 23, 17, 22, 18, 24. As letters that would be TWQVRX, which doesn't seem helpful - it's also not a Caesar or Atbash cipher of anything meaningful. I thought it might be the date, but none of the numbers is small enough to be the month.
6. > The number of words in each subsentence (between punctuation) is 5,8,3,4; 12,11; 7,7,3; 5,10,7; 4,5,9; 5,12,7. As letters that would be EHCD LK GGC EJG DEI ELG, which doesn't seem helpful. Even putting it together with TWQVRX as a Vigenere key doesn't work.

Comment: On the right track, I recommend looking at 2/3 again :)

Comment: Now Jens has found the meaning of 3, there’s just the 2 left. 4-6 are unimportant (but nice ideas that I might have to use in future :P) my most recent edit may be a small hint.

Comment: Another step down! Honestly, I thought I'd made that one too easy with the L for lower, U for upper thing, apparently not :P Who can work out what to do with this image now....

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I've gotta be honest, my enthusiasm about this puzzle waned after finding the image. I was impressed that you could pack so much information into just a short paragraph of text ... but now it seems like you didn't, and there's extra information that you had to hide on Imgur - not only that, but information that, even once found, it's not obvious how to interpret the instructions given.

Comment: I can understand that the imgur maze idea is rather out done. I’m not usually a fan of them, but this puzzle has a nice ending I’ve had in my head for ages and it’s the only way it works. I’m actually trying to work on another puzzle atm where I pack as much as possible in to steganography, but sadly not in this one, hopefully the end won’t be too disappointing, there’s only one/two steps left to complete here, and the image isn’t too complicated when you realise what it’s saying. Sorry it’s let you down a bit :)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil The hint helped me to be sure of what to do with that image. It was one of the options I'd thought of, but there are so many different possible things that could mean (and I was sort of hoping it *wouldn't* involve going to even more Imgur things :-P ) Anyway, solved, I think?

Comment: Yep you got it all now! The idea was I wanted the question itself to give the answers, and the only real way I could think of doing that was, sadly, imgur. The idea was to combine the 'on top' and 'under' to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIRs1.png) (mind if I edit this into your answer?) which gives all the required parts. Probably rushed this, my puzzles haven't done great recently (and even though I know some of thats down to the HNQ formula, still not done well), but you've given me an idea for another puzzle which I'm gonna spend some time to make sure it's as clever as possible :)